# Select only specific part of STRING column

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I have a table with a column "Description", I need to query that table and get only specific part of the Description column.
Here a few examples of what's inside the 'Description' column:

```
|DESCRIPTION|
-------------
|someRandomt|
|it has 0.5g|
|23g is enou|
|otherRandom|
|55g, 0.1g, |
```

In the SELECT statement, I need to select only the different numeric values (float or int) with the letter 'g' behind it and if there are more than one, I need to concatenate them using '/'. The final result in this case should be like this:

```
|DESCRIPTION|
-------------
|null       |
|0.5g       |
|23g        |
|null       |
|55g/0.1g   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the numbers with g by `regexp_extract_all` and then `array_join` to get a single string.

Here is a code example for PySpark.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.withColumn('nums', f.array_join(f.expr('regexp_extract_all(DESCRIPTION, "([0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?g)")'), '/')) \
  .show()

+-----------+--------+
|DESCRIPTION|    nums|
+-----------+--------+
|someRandomt|        |
|it has 0.5g|    0.5g|
|23g is enou|     23g|
|otherRandom|        |
|55g, 0.1g, |55g/0.1g|
+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: What does "f." stands for?
Also is it suppose for regexp_extract_all to be inside quotes?

Comment: Because, I am working on the python, so the functions are imported as f, but it is not needed in scala.

Comment: Ah, right. Other than that, this is a working solution. Thanks a lot.